# Как запретить символ после одного раза его использования?

Tags: javascript, html, css

на мой сайт нужно добавить ввод номера, нужно сделать так, чтобы плюс можно было использовать только один раз, а на второй он не реагировал. По возможности показать на примере, спасибо!

Comment: да возьми плагин и всё))  типа такого https://imask.js.org/

Comment: а если номер украинский, просто заменить символы?

Comment: ну настроить-то наверняка можно.

Comment: ок, спасибо большое

Comment: там вон написана маска `mask: '+{7}(000)000-00-00'`  соответственно вместо 7 ставишь что-то другое

Comment: чёто не работает, можете на примере показать? +38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы просто хотите что в инпут не было второго плюса, то вот тогда(сделано топорно):

```js
const INP = document.querySelector('#i')

INP.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  if(INP.value.includes('++')) INP.value='+'+INP.value.replaceAll('+', '')
})
```

```html
<input id="i" type="text">
```

Я же посоветую сделать так, чтобы + был включён по стандарту и нужно было вводить только числа, а в самом коде если вам нужно номер с +-ом, тогда просто добавляйте его в начало. Вот что я имею в виду:

```js
const INP = document.querySelector('#i')

let phoneNumber

INP.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  phoneNumber = INP.value
  console.log('+42'+phoneNumber)
})
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}

form > span {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-right: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

form > input {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <span>+42</span>
  <input id="i" type="number">
</form>
```

Плюс к этому всему это же решает проблему того, что пользователь может написать к примеру не число, а букву. И это как по мне самый лучший вариант того как это можно реализовать.

Comment: спасибо! Решил проблему

Comment: @РостиславКальченко да кстати в инпуте можно указать максимальную длину значения, то есть можно для номера указать к примеру, что максимальное кол-во цифр это 5, и пользователь сможет написать только так: `+4212345`(грубо говоря), также можно указать минимальное кол-во цифр, по такому же принципу. Атрибуты [`maxlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/maxlength) и [`minlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/minlength)